# PHP integer exponentiation (super large numbers)

Tags: php, numbers, largenumber

Using PHP I want to do millions of 2^n exponentiation but so far I only got up to n^1023 before PHP printed INF.

Any ideas?

Comment: 2^1023 is the upper limit for IEEE double-precision floating point values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [BC Math](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) functions:

```
  $num = bcpow(2, 1000000); // Takes a few seconds to run!
```

Comment: I'll experiment with both BC Math and GMP

Answer (score 5):

As Greg said, [BC Math](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) is fine, but if you really need efficiency, try [GMP](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) instead.